# How to design UDAF on nest array in spark Dataframe

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Input data:

```
+---+----+----+
|idx|  v1|  v2|
+---+----+----+
|  a|   1|   3|
|  a|null|   2|
|  a|   4|   5|
|  b|   6|   1|
|  b|   7|null|
+---+----+----+
```

And what I want:

```
+---+-------------------------------------------+                               
|idx|total                                      |
+---+-------------------------------------------+
|b  |[WrappedArray(6, 7), WrappedArray(1)]      |
|a  |[WrappedArray(1, 4), WrappedArray(3, 2, 5)]|
+---+-------------------------------------------+
```

I know I can get this throuth

```
df.groupBy("idx").agg(array(collect_list(col("v1")), collect_list(col("v2"))));
```

But I want to achieve the result throught **UDAF in JAVA**.

Comment: [GenericUDAFCollectList.java](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/co.cask.cdap/hive-exec/0.13.0/org/apache/hadoop/hive/ql/udf/generic/GenericUDAFCollectList.java) :D